# How to show the "commutate" symbol inside a diagram in LyX?

Tags: lyx, diagrams, xy-pic

I am using this code

```
$$
\xymatrix{
    z\in\ar@{|->}[d] & \mathbb{C}\ar[r]^{f}\ar[d] & \overline{\mathbb{C}}\\
    {}[z]\in & \mathbb{C}/L\ar[ru]_{\hat{f}}
}
$$
```

to generate this diagram in LyX:

[image]

How can I show the arrowed circle inside the triangle (diagram) which mathematically indicates, that the diagram commutes?

Comment: not directly related to your problem, but have a look at [why-is-$$-preferable-to](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to) for reasons not to use `$$...$$`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

this uses "plain" latex, but i believe that can be embedded in a lyx session.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xypic}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\[
\xymatrix{
  \mathbb{C} \ar[r]^f \ar[d]
  \ar@{}[dr] |{\mathstrut\raisebox{2.5ex}{$\circlearrowright$\kern1.4em}}
  & \overline{\mathbb{C}} \\
  \mathbb{C}/L \ar[ru]_{\hat{f}} & \null
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: output of tex code]

the `\null` is used to provide a path on which to set the arrowed circle; an empty `\mbox{}` would do as well.  the position of the arrow is determined by experiment (starting with an educated guess).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tested it and it seems to work. At least I see the circled arrow. I assume, that raise box{2.5ex} is responsible for moving the box of the arrow up. Is there a way to push it to the left, too?

Comment: @Aufwind -- inside the box with the arrow, there is a `\kern` instruction to the right of the arrow.  i used this trick to make the arrow "wider", which has the effect of pushing it to the left.  if you want it shifted more to the left, increase the `1.4em` to whatever looks good to you.  (i'm not familiar with this notation, so just shifted the position until it looked reasonable to me.)